# How to achieve sharp borders using clip-path property

Tags: css

I have an image with the following sharp bottom corners:

[image]

I've tried border-radius but seems it's possible to create only smooth corners.

How to achieve these 'sharp bottom corners' effect using clip-path property or any other css technique?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `::after` and `::before` take a look at this link: https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/
make a shape like those and put them on your background image.
As i figured out on your image your  tag is white so when you color the shape's white they would be invisible and you can also do your corner or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `border-radius` for sharp borders.

```css
#sharp-img {
  border-radius: 0% 0% 31% 33% / 0% 0% 16% 17%;
}
```

```html
<img id="sharp-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80"  width="500" alt="technology" />
```

More visualize at [Fancy Border Radius Generator](https://9elements.github.io/fancy-border-radius/full-control.html#0.0.0.33-83.100.84.69-.).

Comment: I think it's not sharp, take a look closely on the image above and generated with the border-radius. The corners are different.